# Unit Testing ECMAScript Modules (ESM) and Mocking Local State?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, module, mocking, es6-modules

How can I test functions of ECMAScript Modules (ESM) (or JavaScript Modules) that depend on the local state of their module?  Specifically, I want to mock the local state within the module.

From this article http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html, I understand that:

- Modules are singletons.
- In ES6, `import`s are read-only views on `export`s

Thus, while I could export a local variable, and import that local variable from the test and then modifiy it, because it’s read-only I’ll get an error.

**Q)** How can I mock the local state of an ES6 module?  When it's type:

1. Number?
2. Object?
3. Function?

---

Example `sumModule.js` - How can I mock this to set the sum, as I wish that is appropriate, for the test?  Zero, may not be appropriate.

```
let sum = 0 // local state - type number example

export function addToSum (num) {
  sum += num;
  return sum
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by adding a new function intended only for test use:

```
export function setMockNum (mock) {
  num = mock
}
```

And I can do the same for functions and objects too.

It's readable (the intent is clear), and it allows me to move forward.